# How to set PATH in Jenkins Declarative Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, path, environment-variables, jenkins-pipeline

In Jenkins scripted pipeline you can set PATH env variable like this :

```
node {
   git url: 'https://github.com/jglick/simple-maven-project-with-tests.git'
   withEnv(["PATH+MAVEN=${tool 'M3'}/bin"]) {
      sh 'mvn -B verify'
   }
}
```

Notice the *PATH+MAVEN* as explained here https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#code-withenv-code-set-environment-variables :

> A list of environment variables to set, each in the form
>   VARIABLE=value or VARIABLE= to unset variables otherwise defined. You
>   may also use the syntax PATH+WHATEVER=/something to prepend /something
>   to $PATH.

But I didn't find how to do it in declarative pipeline using environment syntax (as explained here : https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/environment).

```
environment {
    DISABLE_AUTH = 'true'
    DB_ENGINE    = 'sqlite'
}
```

Ideally I would like to update the PATH to use custom tools for all my stages.

Answer (score 90):

It is possible with `environment` section:

```
pipeline {
  agent { label 'docker' }
  environment {
    PATH = "/hot/new/bin:${env.PATH}"
  }
  stages {
    stage ('build') {
      steps {
        echo "PATH is: ${env.PATH}"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44380495/1000551) for info.

Comment: That is significantly nicer than the `withEnv(['PATH+WHATEVER=...'])` mess!

Comment: This almost works, but `PATH` is null in the environment block, so when I use this I end up with just `/hot/new/bin` and nothing else.

Comment: This works if I set it at the stage level, rather than pipeline.

Comment: Will this work if you change `$PATH` to `${PATH}` in the environment block?

Comment: @Jeremy it needs to be ${env.PATH}

Comment: This method does not set the PATH variable inside the shell. Try running sh 'echo $PATH', it will not have the /hot/new/bin part. The echo step picks up the path variable through env interpolation of Jenkins. If you are trying to call commands, e.g. a command installed by python pip, this solution does not work for appending $HOME/.local/bin to the PATH.

Comment: `environment { PATH = "...:$PATH" }` worked just fine for me.

Answer (score 7):

As a workaround, you can define an environment variable and use it in the `sh` step:

```
pipeline {
    environment {
        MAVEN_HOME = tool('M3')
    }

    stages {
        stage(Maven') {
           sh '${MAVEN_HOME}/bin/mvn -B verify'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the `tool` function defined?

Comment: It's predefined, but you need the tool to be configured in the global settings: https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#tool-use-a-tool-from-a-predefined-tool-installation

Comment: Could you do something like MAVEN_HOME = powershell("doSomething") - where doSomething is a function defined on the system path? I'm trying to call a powershell script that will return the location of python.

Comment: I see there is a `powershell` function, so `powershell(script = "doSomething", returnStdout = true)` might work, but I never tried it.

Comment: The workaround does not answer the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Check the following link, this explains how to configure your tools.
Using the declarative pipeline things become a bit different but overall it is easier to understand.

[declarative-maven-project](https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/02/07/declarative-maven-project/)

Answer (score 1):

Using the tool section in pipeline is only allowed for pre-installed Global Tools. Some tools are provided by plugins, but if it not exists I'am afraid you cannot use the environment setup via pipeline tool declaration.

I hope to be wrong!

Comment: See my answer below