# Export command in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, path, export, jenkins-pipeline

How to add an 'export' unix command in a Jenkins pipeline?
I have a Jenkins 'stage' and 'steps' within it. What is the syntax for an export command. I need to set the environment variable 'PATH' using the export command.

Answer (score 17):

You can update the `$PATH` like this:

```
pipeline {
  agent { label 'docker' }
  stages {
    stage ('build') {
      steps {

        // JENKINSHOME is just a name to help readability
        withEnv(['PATH+JENKINSHOME=/home/jenkins/bin']) {
          echo "PATH is: $PATH"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I run this the result is:

```
[Pipeline] echo
PATH is: /home/jenkins/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

What the heck is this `PATH+JENKINSHOME` syntax? Quoting from a [blog at designhammer.com](https://designhammer.com/blog/building-groovy-pipeline):

This:

```
/my/additional/path:$PATH
```

is expressed as:

```
PATH+ANYSTRING=/my/additional/path.
```

`ANYSTRING` is just a name to help readability. If it doesn't help readability, in your view, you can omit it. So this is equivalent:

```
PATH+=/my/additional/path
```

The above (`withEnv`) allows you to update the `$PATH` for a specific part of your pipeline. To update the `$PATH` for the entire pipeline, you can't use the `PATH+ANYSTRING` syntax, but this works:

```
pipeline {
  agent { label 'docker' }
  environment {
    PATH = "/hot/new/bin:$PATH"
  }
  stages {
    stage ('build') {
      steps {
        echo "PATH is: $PATH"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Produces output:

```
[Pipeline] echo
PATH is: /hot/new/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

Comment: When running in a docker container the `$PATH` needs to be escaped, otherwise it will be expanded in Jenkins not in the container. When used in the `steps` block.

Comment: Setting `PATH` in the `stage` `environment` block does not work. I haven't figured out why. If I set it in the main `environment` block from `pipeline` then the whole pipeline is affected, which I don't need. I need this just for the testing stage.

I've ended up with  `export PATH=foo:\$PATH` in the `sh` block in `steps`. This works.

Comment: It wasn't working in `environment` for me because `PATH` was nil, so this had the effect of overriding the path. I ended up just using absolute paths to my executables.

Comment: What would be the equivalent if jenkins is on Windows?