# Jenkins with Docker on Windows - Cannot run program "nohup"

Tags: windows, azure, docker, jenkins

I am using the [Jenkins Azure VM Agents Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/azure-vm-agents) with a Linux Master, to launch jobs on Windows agents.

I have been through all the configuration steps and everything works fine until I try to use Docker on the agents.

My pipeline script:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'myurl.io/myimage:latest'
            registryUrl 'https://myurl.io/'
            registryCredentialsId '123456789abcdefg'
        }
    }
```

The pipeline appears to fails on when it runs this command:

```
docker pull myurl.io/myimage:latest
```

The error reported comes down to this:

```
Caused: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "nohup" (in directory "C:\Jenkins\workspace\Test Pipeline Docker"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

Some notes:

- I have ticked the box to install git on the image:
  [image]
- The Git tools appear to be successfully installed on the agent VM
- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45140614/jenkins-pipeline-sh-fail-with-cannot-run-program-nohup-on-windows) seems to be related but is it not exactly the same

  - I am not running the `sh` command directly, it is being run by the plugin.
  - I do not think I have access to set the `PATH` at this stage
- This issue on JIRA https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-36776 is related, but it does not seems to be fixed and the suggested workarounds don't seem to apply to my situation

My question

Is there a way to get my pipeline script to work? Maybe there are some extra commands I can somehow execute on the agent after it launches - but before the `docker pull` command - to add the required directories to the `PATH`?

Or is there some other workaround?

Comment: Interested, I have same problem. Did you resolved?

Comment: @realtebo No, I haven't resolved it yet, but I haven't tried again for a while.

Comment: Might it be possible to provide a file `nohup.bat` which just executes all of its parameters normally to resolve the absence of `nohup` on Windows?

Comment: I am going to with `nohup` is a unix command and the agent is a Win server. Search S/O for ["[jenkins] nohup 'c:\' is:question"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjenkins%5D+nohup+%27c%3A%5C%27+is%3Aquestion) for suggestions to fix.

Comment: it looks like your Jenkins slave cannot access the nohup command on your machine. Have you checked your Jenkins in the configuration --> tools where is the path of your git-tools?

Answer (score 1):

I think you were on the right track with the question you already found:
[Jenkins pipeline sh fail with "cannot run program nohup" on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45140614/jenkins-pipeline-sh-fail-with-cannot-run-program-nohup-on-windows)

But, according to the wiki page of the docker-pipeline plugin, running docker on windows workers is not supported (a bit hidden though...):

> For Jenkins environments which have macOS, Windows, or other agents, which are unable to run the Docker daemon, this default setting may be problematic. [https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/#specifying-a-docker-label]

As far as I can see, there were several tries to add that feature, but it doesn't seem to be added (yet): https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-workflow-plugin/pull/148

In the last link it is also stated, that fixing the sh/nohup issue will not be your only problem, for example the docker plugin will try to run `id` to get the user.

Nevertheless, you *could* try to make linux commands available by editing the path in your pipeline declaration:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45101214/12338776

EDIT:
Just saw this question is 3 years old... Well. But since there was no answer so far, and a lot of people still seem to get here, it might still help someone.