# Docker Jenkins - Automatically installed Maven + Open Java not working together

Tags: docker, jenkins, java-home, automatic-install

**Jenkins**

Installed from docker image [jenkinsci/docker - README.me](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/README.md)

**Plugins**

[Pipeline Maven Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Maven+Plugin)

**configureTools**

1. JDK :

   - name : Java 10
   - install automatically : true (extract *.zip/*.tar.gz)
   - url : https://download.java.net/java/GA/jdk10/10.0.2/19aef61b38124481863b1413dce1855f/13/openjdk-10.0.2_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
2. Maven :

   - name : Default
   - install automatically : true (Install from Apache)
   - version : 3.6.0

**Jenkinsfile**

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Clean') {
            steps {
                withMaven(maven: 'Default',jdk: 'Java 10') {
                    sh "echo JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME"
                    sh "mvn clean"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Error**

> [Pipeline] // stage
>   [Pipeline] withEnv
>   [Pipeline] {
>   [Pipeline] stage
>   [Pipeline] { (Clean)
>   [Pipeline] withMaven
>   [withMaven] Options: []
>   [withMaven] Available options:
>   [withMaven] using JDK installation Java 10
>   [withMaven] using Maven installation 'Default'
>   [Pipeline] {
>   [Pipeline] sh
>   + echo 'JAVA_HOME=/var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.model.JDK/Java_10'
>   JAVA_HOME=/var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.model.JDK/Java_10
>   [Pipeline] sh
>   + mvn clean -B -V
>   ----- withMaven Wrapper script -----
>   The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
>   This environment variable is needed to run this program
>   NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE
>   [Pipeline] }

**Question**
What I don't understand is why the `$JAVA_HOME` is incorrect ? (should be  */var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.model.JDK/Java_10/jdk-10.0.2*, no ?)
I've try to set it on the global properties of the jenkins system configuration, but I've get the same output/error (and don't want to set it here as there can be other java_home for other java installation)
What am I missing ?

---

*EDIT*
Opened an issue to Jenkins ([Jira - JENKINS-54959](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-54959))

---

*EDIT 2*
After some discussion with the Jenkins crews, we finally found the missing option.
As the archive contains a subdirectory (here *jdk-10.0.2*), we need to inform the de-zipper with the subdir field

> Optional subdirectory of the downloaded and unpacked archive to use as the tool's home directory

so now, I got the error

> [Pipeline] withMaven
>   [withMaven] Options: []
>   [withMaven] Available options: 
>   [withMaven] using JDK installation Java 10
>   [withMaven] using Maven installation 'Default'
>   [Pipeline] {
>   [Pipeline] sh
>   + echo 'JAVA_HOME=/var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.model.JDK/Java_10/jdk-10.0.2'
>   JAVA_HOME=/var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.model.JDK/Java_10/jdk-10.0.2
>   [Pipeline] sh
>   + mvn clean -B -V
>   ----- withMaven Wrapper script -----
>   /var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Default/bin/mvn: exec: line 199: /var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.model.JDK/Java_10/jdk-10.0.2/bin/java: not found
>   [Pipeline] }

Comment: According to [this blog about declarative maven project](https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/02/07/declarative-maven-project/) I found via [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43254747/201725) to a related question you should have a `tools` section in the pipeline stating you want to use the tools. It is common to have many tools, but only use a few in each pipeline, so you have to tell it.

Comment: shouldn't need to declare ``tools`` section as I'm using withMaven (I added the plugin on the description)
But I've tried (in case of), but same error, the ``JAVA_HOME`` is still incomplete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK,

by installing the [Java 11 Support Preview is available in Jenkins 2.155+](https://jenkins.io/blog/2018/12/14/java11-preview-availability/) I'm not anymore having the java error \o/

I'm closing this problem :)

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work if you set the "Subdirectory of extracted archive" of the JDK configuration:

[image: workaround1]

Comment: What version of Jenkins were you running? I have `Jenkins ver. 2.204.2` and when checking the box `Install automatically` and clicking options from drop-down (i.e. Extract *.zip, etc.) does not show other fields.