# Change environment variable when using Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, environment-variables, environment

I'm trying to use Jenkins for running  python tests and creating coverage reports.

I have compiled application that is bound with python - lets call it pythonX - that setts up environment for executing parts of that application. Now, when I want to run tests for some part of the code I can just run

`d:\my_app\sys\pythonX.exe -m pytest d:\user\repos\my_app\tests\unit`

and all works really nice because `pythonX` knows where everything is.

For that I'm using

```
stage('Run tests') {
        steps {
            bat 'd:\\my_app\\sys\\pythonX.exe -m pytest d:\\user\\repos\\my_app\\tests\\unit'
        }
}
```

.
But there is a problem, this `pythonX` is running the tests on the code that is shipped with the application, so already built and all that. What I wan't is to run tests on the code that is still local.

The `pythonX` adds a environment variable `PYTHONPATH` for specifying where the source code is but whenever I start the `pythonX.exe` via `bat` it changes whatever I've added before.

What I've tried first is using the `withEnv` like so

```
stage('Run tests') {
        steps {
            withEnv(['PATH+PYTHONPATH=d:\\user\\repos\\my_app']){
                bat 'd:\\my_app\\sys\\pythonX.exe -m pytest d:\\user\\repos\\my_app\\tests\\unit'
            }
        }
}
```

but it doesn't help.

What I've tried is else is setting up the environment, then changing the `PYTHONPATH` variable, and then running the tests via `pythonX` in existing environment.
This is the code

```
stage('Run tests') {
        steps {
            bat '''
            d:\\my_app\\sys\\pythonX.exe  --debug=cmd
            set PYTHONPATH= d:\\user\\repos\\my_app;%PYTHONPATH%
            d:\\my_app\\sys\\pythonX.exe -m pytest d:\\user\\repos\\my_app\\tests\\unit
            '''
        }
}
```

but this doesn't work. I presume that is overwrites the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable with it's own.
Does anyone know how to overcome this?

Comment: Are you sure the variables aren't getting set?  In the examples provided, I don't see anything echoing/printing the values of the variables after the attempt to set them.

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43237051/how-to-set-path-in-jenkins-declarative-pipeline